# Avoid reopen datepicker after select a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, datepicker

Only in IE with this code

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect : function(x, u){
     $(this).focus();   
    }
});
```

when I select a date, the datepicker reopen itself because I added `$(this).focus();` in `onSelect`. How I can to resolve this issue? ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VZts7/61/))

I'm using jquery 1.8.2 and jquery-ui 1.9

Comment: this link might help http://forum.jquery.com/topic/avoid-reopening-of-the-datepicker-in-ie-after-this-datepicker-setdate-mydate

Comment: is it that important to set focus after selection? There are numerous events to tap into within datepicker API. My guess is jQuery UI team removed the focus in IE for the same reason

Comment: @al0neevenings ..I don't understand how that link could fix my issue :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the best workaround i can get:

(inspired from [this link](http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/06/18/jquery-ui-datepicker-ie-focus-fix/))

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hv77F/)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
            /* fix buggy IE focus functionality */
            fixFocusIE: false,    
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                  this.fixFocusIE = true;
                        $(this).change().focus();
            },
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                  this.fixFocusIE = true;
                  this.focus();
            },
            beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                  var result = $.browser.msie ? !this.fixFocusIE : true;
                  this.fixFocusIE = false;
                  return result;
            }
}).click(function(){$(this).focus()});
```

Please note as you suggested in your question, im using jquery-UI 1.9.0. In your sample, you were using jquery-ui 1.8.15 which is known to be buggy on some events (e.g  beforeShow() on IE).

Comment: +1 required to use 1.9.0 jquery-ui version due to buggy implementation of beforeShow event in previous versions

Comment: This does not work in jQuery > 1.9 in IE <= 9 http://jsfiddle.net/hv77F/22/ The internet needs a solution to this, should anyone have sufficient time donate to a worthy cause!

Comment: @user1477388 -- Try adding an empty (or, for JSLint, a `return undefined;`) `onSelect` handler. Haven't figured out why that works, but it's working for me so far (YMMV).

Comment: Does not work for me (IE11). No any working solution found so far. And BTW $.browser is deprecated in new jQuery.

Answer (score 12):

I came across this issue today and had a different solution work for me. My scenario was that my DatePicker was inside a jQuery UI Dialog popup. Everything worked fine in Chrome, but in IE, the calendar would always reappear after selecting a date.

As it turns out, there is an open bug for this in jQuery 1.10.1: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9125

There is also a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9AT2/1/) linked to that demonstrates the bug in IE. There are two ways to get this to work in IE:

1. Set `modal` to `false`
2. Focus on another element right after date selection

I went with #2, and here is an example of the fix (just updating the JSFiddle code):

Markup:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <input id="datepicker" />
    <input type='button' value='save' id='btnSave'/>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({onSelect: function() { $('#btnSave').focus(); }});
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ modal: true });
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Very thorough answer, thanks.  I went ahead and upvoted that bug on bugs.jqueryui.com.  Also, I ended up using #2 solution you suggested as well.  I default focus to the cancel button in case they accidentally hit enter.

Comment: Hmmm actually a problem I ran into after using solution #2 is that I had hooked up a function to the change event for the textbox the DatePicker was created on.... and the change event didn't fire anymore.  So instead of using solution #2... I put <span tabindex="4"></span> type of elements between each textbox/datepicker, so that they would be focused on by default instead of the datepickers after I select a date.  After I select a date in my 2nd datepicker, it harmlessly sets focus to my empty span now.  Just make sure you set your tabindex attribute to what makes sense for your page.

Answer (score 5):

I use this for IE, it stops the datepicker re-opening too

JQuery:

```
        onSelect: function(){ 
        $("#focusfix").focus();
    },
```

HTML (first line of the dialog div):

```
<input class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" id="focusfix" type="text"autofocus/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `.browser` is removed after jQuery 1.9 I had to slightly modify the code. This works for me:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    /* fix buggy IE focus functionality */
    fixFocusIE: false,    
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          this.fixFocusIE = true;
                $(this).change().focus();
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
          this.fixFocusIE = true;
          this.focus();
    },
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
          var result = true;
          if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            result = !this.fixFocusIE;
          }
          this.fixFocusIE = false;
          return result;
    }
}).click(function(){$(this).focus()});
```

Comment: IE 11 returns a value of 'Netscape' for `navigator.appName` along with Chrome/Safari/Firefox apparently.  Rather than check for both values I removed the conditional all together and didn't notice any difference in the non-IE browsers.  Can anyone think of a reason to retain the conditional (`if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
onSelect : function(x, u){
 $(this).focus(); 
   $(this).datepicker("hide");     
},
onClose: function(e){
e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VZts7/69/

Or for **IE8**:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
onSelect : function(x, u){
 $(this).focus();     
},
onClose: function(e){
(this).datepicker("hide");   
}
});
```

even if it's not a perfect solution see working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hv77F/2/

Comment: It's works, but there is an exeception "Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault' "

Comment: nothig! Now the error is "event is not defined" because, I suppose, "OnClose" accept only two parameters "dateTxt" and "inst" (instance of datepicker)

Comment: with "e" i don't see anymore the error, but the datepicker reopen itself :(

Comment: the fiddle full works in IE8 but roasted answer is better than mine, see his answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution for jQuery > 1.9 in IE <= 9

```
{fixFocusIE: false},    
        {onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              this.fixFocusIE = true;
              $(this).change().focus();

            }
        },
        {onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
              this.fixFocusIE = true;
              this.focus();

            }
        },
        {beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
              var result = isIE ? !this.fixFocusIE : true;                      
              this.fixFocusIE = false;                      
              return result;
         }

function isIE() {
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0)      
           return true;
        else                 

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing.
I had the same problem, except none of the answers mentioned here worked.
It may be because the code I have to work on works with iframes, but I don't now for sure.
On top, I couldn't update to the latest version, because it would break compatibility with the rest of the project I had to work on. 
So this is what fixed it for me:

```
initDatePicker: function ()
{
    // Initialize datepicker 
    var qs = document.getElementsByClassName("datepick");
    for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; ++i)
    {
        $(qs[i]).datepicker(
        {
            // showOn: "button"
            // showOn: "both"
              showOn: "focus"
            , buttonImage: "../images/cal.gif"
            , buttonImageOnly: true
            //, buttonImageOnly: false
            , dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
            , changeMonth: true
            , changeYear: true
            , showWeek: false // true
            , firstDay: 1
            , showOtherMonths: true //false 
            , selectOtherMonths: true
            , showButtonPanel: true


            //,onSelect : function(x, u){
            //    // $(this).focus(); 

            //    window.setTimeout(function () { $("#txtSchulungsTyp").focus(); $(this).datepicker("hide"); }, 300);
            //},
            //onClose: function(e){
            //    // e.preventDefault();
            //    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
            //    return false;
            //}



            , onSelect: function ()
            {
                $(this).datepicker('disable');
            }
            , onClose: function ()
            {
                window.setTimeout(function (e)
                {
                    $(e).datepicker('enable')
                }.bind(undefined, this), 500)
            }

        })
        ; // End datepicker


        // console.log(mGlobalLanguage);

        // $(qs[i]).datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional['de']);  
        // $(qs[i]).datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional['FR']);
    } // Next i 
}
```